# KendoUI Grid Populate adjacent cell on selection from AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an AutoComplete set up all working for one of the cells in my grid.

How do I select the next adjacent `<td>` or `input` so that I can populate it with a value I specify?

I know the first thing I need to change is that the id needs to go on the input. So all it is, is just a case of selecting the next cell/input along.

Here is my dropdown code:

```
function partNumberScanner(container, options)
{
  $('<input id="partEntry" class="k-input k-textbox" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
  .appendTo(container);
  $('#partEntry').kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "idealForm",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: {
      serverFiltering: true,
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: ROOT+"part/fetchParts",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json"
        }
      },
      error: function(e) {
        alert(e.errorThrown+"\n"+e.status+"\n"+e.xhr.responseText) ;
      },
      schema: {
        id: "id",

      }
    },
    change: function(e)
    {

    },
    minLength: 5,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Start typing...",
    change: function(e) {
      selectedPart = this.value();
      alert(this.element[0].id)

      $(this).next('td').val(selectedPart);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Don't you know the name of the `field` in the adjacent cell?

Comment: @OnaBai, Yes, but more rows will be added so it won't know which input with name 'manufacturer' to select :(

Comment: So the problem is actually finding the row not the column, right? I mean because it's easier finding the row, then get the `dataItem` for that row and finally `set` the new value known the name of the field that we want to update.

Comment: @OnaBai It is both, as I need to tell it to select the next field (manufacturer) and stop there, not carrying on and end up selecting the last one in the grid. Once I have the selector for it I can easily populate it with data from another datasource.

Comment: @OnaBai Think I was coming at it from the wrong angle. I have just altered the object property in my data array using partData[0].manufacturer = manufacturer; and then sync() the grids datasource.

Comment: Much better, the problem navigating the HTML is that Kendo UI decorates it with a lot of HTML elements, CSS classes,... and the structure is not always the expected. You should try to go to the dataItems and work from there. Glad you solve it!

Comment: @OnaBai Thanks for all your help so far! One more thing I can't seem to do, is how do I get the value of a parameter in the dataSource when I select an item from the drop down?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26722/discussion-between-onabai-and-imperium2335)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define select as:

```
select        : function (e) {
    var index = e.item.index();
    var item = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
}
```

Where `index` is the number of the entry selected in the `AutoComplete` and `item` contains the information from the DataSource used in the AutoComplete.